# create a hyperlink that executes a bash/python on the user machine

Tags: python, html, bash, jinja2

Is it possible to create a hyperlink/button that calls a bash/python script on the user/local machine. I did search on the topic but there is a lot of discussion about the opening a port to a server (even the local port) but I don't want to open a port but execute everything locally. Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: A website cannot cause a browser to run code locally. Consider the security implications of that.

Comment: Is the script already on the user machine?

Comment: yes the script is already on the user machine

Answer (score 0):

No.  That is not possible.  Nor desirable, due to the security implications.